# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) implementation

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I'm implementing Curiously Recurring Template Pattern(CRTP) in Java as follows.

The Interface:

```
/**
 * Reason for the generic Value<T extends Value>
 * Value<IntValue> x; // legal, IntValue implements Value interface so allowed
 * Value<Integer> x;  // illegal, does not implement Value interface  
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public interface Value<T extends Value> {
    T deepCopy();
}
```

Classes implementing it:

```
public class IntValue implements Value<IntValue> {
    Integer value;

    public IntValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public IntValue deepCopy() {
        return new IntValue(value);
    }
}
/**
* // Valid
* List<IntValue> ints = Arrays.asList(new IntValue(Integer.valueOf(5)));
* ArrayValue<IntValue> arr = new ArrayValue<>(ints);
*
* // Invalid
* List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(5));
* ArrayValue<Integer> arr = new ArrayValue<>(ints); 
*/
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class ArrayValue<T extends Value> implements Value<ArrayValue<T>> {

    List<T> values;

    public ArrayValue() {
        this(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public ArrayValue(List<T> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public ArrayValue<T> deepCopy() {
        List<? super Value> copyValues = new ArrayList<>();
        values.forEach(value -> copyValues.add(value.deepCopy()));
        return new ArrayValue<T>((List<T>) copyValues);
    }
}

//Static Function using the interface
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static Value sub(Value a, Value b) 
{
    if(a instanceof IntValue && b instanceof IntValue)
    {
        return new IntValue( ((IntValue)a).getValue() - ((IntValue)b).getValue());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TypeMismatchException("Operation not supported");
    }
    return NullValue.NULL_VALUE;
}
```

However I have to suppress warnings multiple times throughout the implementation.

Are the uses of suppress annotation justified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I can tell this doesn't generate any warnings:

```
class IntValue implements Value<IntValue> {

    Integer value;

    public IntValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public IntValue deepCopy() {
        return new IntValue(value);
    }
}


class ArrayValue<T extends Value<T>> implements Value<ArrayValue<T>> {

    List<T> values;

    public ArrayValue() {
        this(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public ArrayValue(List<T> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayValue<T> deepCopy() {
        List<T> copyValues = new ArrayList<>();
        values.forEach(value -> copyValues.add(value.deepCopy()));
        return new ArrayValue<>(copyValues);
    }
}
```

But it makes more sense to do it without CRTP:

```
public interface Value<T> {
    Value<T> deepCopy();
    T getValue();
}


class IntValue implements Value<Integer> {

    Integer value;

    public IntValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public IntValue deepCopy() {
        return new IntValue(value);
    }
}


class ArrayValue<T> implements Value<List<Value<T>>> {

    List<Value<T>> values;

    public ArrayValue() {
        this(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public ArrayValue(List<Value<T>> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayValue<T> deepCopy() {
        List<Value<T>> copyValues = new ArrayList<>();
        values.forEach(value -> copyValues.add(value.deepCopy()));
        return new ArrayValue<>(copyValues);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Value<T>> getValue() {
        return values;
    }
}

class X {

    public static Value sub(Value<Integer> a, Value<Integer> b) {
         return new IntValue(b.getValue() - b.getValue());
    }
}
```